# C++ Cmath.h issue leading to variables not being in theglobal namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, cmath

When running C++ in visual studio, I'm trying to write a simple Hello World command. However, when I do, I keep getting this issue.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\math.h(1,1): warning C4821: Unable to determine Unicode encoding type, please save the file with signature (BOM) 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(24,18): error C2039: 'fabs': is not a member of '`global namespace'' 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(24,22): error C3861: 'fabs': identifier not found 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(28,18): error C2039: 'fabsf': is not a member of '`global namespace'' 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(28,23): error C3861: 'fabsf': identifier not found 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(32,18): error C2039: 'fabsl': is not a member of '`global namespace'' 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(32,23): error C3861: 'fabsl': identifier not found 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath(26,47): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath(30,18): error C2039: 'acosf': is not a member of '`global namespace'' 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath(30,23): error C3861: 'acosf': identifier not found 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath(34,18): error C2039: 'acoshf': is not a member of '`global namespace'' 
(etc)
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The issue seems to be coming from inside the cmath header file at these lines.

```
_NODISCARD _Check_return_ inline float acos(_In_ float _Xx) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
    return _CSTD acosf(_Xx);
}

_NODISCARD _Check_return_ inline float acosh(_In_ float _Xx) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
    return _CSTD acoshf(_Xx);
}

_NODISCARD _Check_return_ inline float asin(_In_ float _Xx) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
    return _CSTD asinf(_Xx);
}
```

I should note that these errors exist for the bulk of the cmath header file, not just the ones shown here but I didn't think it was useful to include the hundreds of errors.

Is this something to do with Visual Studio dependencies? is there a way I can avoid this error?

I'm working on a clean visual studio install.

Comment: Are you by chance using a precompiled header?

Comment: If I am I'm not intentionally doing it. How do I check if i am? I'm sorry, I'm new to using visual.

Comment: Right click the project, go to properties, C/C++, Precompiled Headers. First line in that should say "Not Using Precompiled Headers"

Comment: I changed that, the entry was blank but I changed it to "Not Using Precompiled Headers." Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Alright, just checking. Sometimes precompiled headers cause issues. When you compile, are the errors still there? Error `Exxxx` is an intellisense error, which aren't always real errors. Compiler errors would start with a `C`

Comment: Yes, the E0282 errors are still there but if I go to the bottom, I get the C errors. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2039 'acoshf': is not a member of '`global namespace'' ConsoleApplication5 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath 34 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C3861 'acoshf': identifier not found ConsoleApplication5 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath 34

Comment: Are the `C` errors the same? The `C`s are the important ones. Can you update the question in include the C errors, and remove the E errors? Also, from the "output" window, as opposed to the "error" window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206299/discussion-between-william-milestone-and-chrismm).

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of pain, I figured out the issue. Basically my math.h file had become corrupt and was just posting NULLS.

I went into the UCRT file in windows kits and copied a math.h file from a previous distrobution. Everything works fine now.

The same trick works for going into your project properties and changing your SDK version to a version separate from your current one.